# Get time calculation from momentJS duration

Tags: javascript, string, momentjs

I have a field in my table that I would like to sort. That field contains strings from MomentJS duration calculation. For example "20 Minutes", "10 Hours 1 Minute" and so on. 
If I want to use a sort function I need to format that string back to lowest resolution of time I have which is minutes. 
Like this: a: "20 Minutes" => 20.
           b: "10 Hours 1 Minute" => 10*60 + 1 = 601.
So when sorting in a descending order b will come before a.

I made this function that does work but it is really hardcoded so I would really like to see other ways to solve it. Thanks!

```
function getTimeFromDuration(duration) {
    const str = duration.split(' ');
    const durationArray = ['Minute', 'Minutes', 'Hour', 'Hours', 'Day', 'Days'];
    const calcArr = [];
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
        const isNum = !isNaN(str[i]);
        const isDuration = durationArray.includes(str[i]) > -1;
        if (isNum) {
            calcArr.push(parseInt(str[i]));
        }
        else if (isDuration) {
            switch(str[i]) {
                case 'Minute':
                case 'Minutes':
                    calcArr.push(1);
                    break;
                case 'Hour':
                case 'Hours':
                    calcArr.push(60);
                    break;
                case 'Day':
                case 'Days':
                    calcArr.push(60*24);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (let j=0; j<calcArr.length; j=j+2) {
        sum+= calcArr[j]*calcArr[j+1];
    }

 return sum;
}


 console.log(getTimeFromDuration('1 Day 1 Hour 20 Minutes'));
```

Comment: Assuming it's a DB table, the best / most elegant way would be to store it in a format which would allow it to be sorted by the DB engine.

Comment: "best" and "elegant" are subjective requirements.  I think your question will be closed as opinion-based.  You also don't describe what this table is.  Is it an HTML table?

Comment: What is wrong with questions that are looking for creative solutions?

Comment: There is no problem with "creative solutions."  Rephrase your questions requirements so they aren't subjective.

Comment: @Razvan And it's not a BE issue. all calculations are in the FE

Comment: Your question is less subjective, but we still don't know what table you're talking about.  Are you using some HTML table sorting library?  We need a [mcve].

Comment: I'm using reactTable package but that fact is irrelevant. I'm trying to create my own custom sorting function. the one that gets two values and compare between them. I'm just looking for the way to do it.

Comment: If you don't need help with the table itself, then you should just limit your question to sorting an array of strings or something like that. Then you could post some sample input data and expected output (which will likely go a long way toward getting someone to post an answer).

Comment: @benvc thanks I've added my own function. Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you retain the original `duration` object with each row, in a `data` attribute, perhaps?  It would make it a *lot* easier if you didn't have to perform the parsing operation.

Comment: @Amy agreed but unfortunately It happens in a complete different code area and it seems wrong to use a state management like Redux to keep this array of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a parsing function in Moment or elsewhere that will handle these types of strings. If your input strings are consistently formatted and limited to days, hours and minutes, then parsing them should not be all that difficult. Following is an approach along the lines of your original function, just a bit more compact due to some effort put into splitting the string into each duration "chunk" and then normalizing the duration descriptor (lowercase and singular) so you can easily access values from a multiplier object.

That said, if your original data contains the Moment duration object rather than just the string representation, then there are easier ways to do this.

```js
const getMinutes = (s) => {
  const multipliers = { day: 1440, hour: 60, minute: 1 };
  const durations = s.split(/\s(?=\d)/);
  let minutes = 0;
  for (const d of durations) {
    let [n, interval] = d.split(' ');
    n = Number(n);
    interval = interval.toLowerCase();
    if (interval.endsWith('s')) {
      interval = interval.slice(0, -1);
    }
    
    minutes += n * multipliers[interval];
  }
  
  return minutes;
};

const result = getMinutes('1 Day 1 Hour 20 Minutes');
console.log(result);
// 1520
```